# redis makefile help, cannot compile additional 3rd party component

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile

I am having a problem with this redis makefile. The error I get is:

```
No rule to make target '../../DB/libx_db.a', needed by 'alchemy-server'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/user/alchemydb2/redis-2.8.17/src'
Makefile:3: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

EDIT: Fixed, forgot to specify to build the libx_db.a before building the component that relied on it.

Comment: Did you run make/etc. in the DB directory to generate that library? I assume you aren't supposed to have to do that but the makefile doesn't seem to be handling this for you at the moment.

Comment: there is no make/etc in the DB directory? Where did you see that?

Comment: The issue is weird because the original makefile (redis 2.3) compiles just fine. Its redis 2.8 thats messing it up. Should i include the 2.8 makefile?

Comment: That was `make`/etc. meaning did you actually build the library manually? The patch for the redis makefile might be better to show (and hopefully smaller). The problem is that make (for redis) doesn't know how to build that library. To teach it how to do that a rule needs to be added which tells it what to do (I assume the patch does that) short of that the library must already exist in that location.

Comment: Ok added those details. DB makes just fine (invoked from DB/) and produces libx_db.a. But using this redis make file, it ends up deleting libx_db.a out of the DB folder and gives that error.

Comment: Ok i see dependencies is used by alchemy-lib which I forgot to include in all:, and its missing.